# Unpublish an item using Experience Editor Mode in Sitecore

Tags: experience-editor, sitecore-mvc

I have a requirement to be able to unpublish an item using experience editor mode in Sitecore. It requires to either unpublish a module as a whole or to unpublish a particular item from that module(as we are using dynamic placeholders). Currently, I only see an option to publish an item. Any thoughts on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you define a "Module"? Publishing only really relates to items.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure which version of Sitecore you are on though. But with newer versions of Sitecore, e.g. Sitecore 9.1, you can certainly do that from Experience Editor too, similar to how you do from the Content Editor. From the "**Home**" Tab, click on "**Settings**". You should see a dialog box open for **Publishing Settings** as can be seen in the below screenshot. There you can either select any version you want to unpublish or the Item as a whole. If you select the item, you would see the "**Publishable**" checkbox. Just uncheck that, click on "Ok" and save it. If you want to do it for Versions, click on the "**Versions**" tab and you will see, **Publishable from**, **Publishable To**, and **Publishable** fields there too, for all the versions of the selected item. If you are not seeing this "Settings" option in your "Home" tab, you would need to provide access for it to your user or role.

[image: Experience Editor-Unpublish]

But if its previous versions of Sitecore, wherein even if you are logged in as an admin, but you still do not see this button there, you can simply copy the "Button" responsible for marking it unpublishable, to your Page Editor/Experience Editor's menu ribbon. Tried and tested steps are as below based on Sitecore 7.1:

1. Log in to core DB.
2. Navigate to "/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Ribbons/Chunks/Publish Restrictions".
3. Right-click on "Publish Restrictions", and select "Copying" -> "Copy To". And then select the "Sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Ribbons/WebEdit/Page Editor" and then click "Copy" at the bottom. Then you should see this button at path "Sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Ribbons/WebEdit/Page Editor" that path too. The screenshot below for reference:

[image: Page/Experience Editor]

4. Now open any page in Page Editor/Experience Editor, and you should start seeing the "Change" button there, from where you can mark it unpublishable.

Screenshot below for reference:
[image]